# RPy2 cannot import _rinterface_capi

Tags: python, rpy2

I haven't used RPy2 for a number of years (and then I only played around a bit). However, I now want to start using Python and R a bit more seriously and decided to re-explore the RPy2 library.

I'm using a Mac running El Capitan. I created a new virtual environment (called env34) using Python 3.4.4 and installed the latest version of pip (19.1.1) using get-pip.py. I then pip installed numpy, pandas and jupyter into the activated environment. I also pip installed RPy2 (but had to include a trusted-host flag):

```
(env34) $ pip install rpy2 --trusted-host=https://pypi.org/simple/cffi
```

I also installed the latest version of R (3.6.0) in the default location in Applications folder and edited .bash_profile to create a RHOME environment variable by adding the following:

```
RHOME="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
export RHOME
```

Now when I launch Python in the virtual environment, I can import rpy2 with no problems. However, I'm trying to follow the tutorial given at http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/rpy2.html and when I try to import rpy2.robjects using:

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects import r
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path_to_virtual_environment/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/path_to_virtual_environment/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface_lib._rinterface_capi as _rinterface
  File "/path_to_virtual_environment/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/_rinterface_capi.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import conversion
  File "/path_to_virtual_environment/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _rinterface_capi as _rinterface
ImportError: cannot import name '_rinterface_capi'
```

As far as I can see, all the files referenced in the message exist in the correct locations.

Can anyone interpret this error message and perhaps offer a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rpy2 might require Python >= 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try that and report back...

Comment: @lgautier: I created a virtual environment with Python 3.6.1 and that does indeed seem to have fixed the problem. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: rpy2 should prevent the installation if Python < 3.5. The tracking of the issue is here: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/547